What's the best JWT authorization approach for allowing resource access for the owner and administrators only?
I need to modify my JWT authentication and authorization for my application, which has CRUD operations for my entities.
Here is what my entity looks like:
public class Entity
{
   public Guid UserId {get; set;}
   // rest of the properties
}

I want to ensure that the delete endpoint is accessible only to the owner and administrators. Currently, I'm using claim-based JWT tokens with an ActionFilterAttribute to check the IsAdmin claim. However, I'm looking for a solution that does not require retrieving the object from the database. Is there any way to achieve this?

Give Authorization details in WebAPI Methods. Like below.`// Restrict by user:
[Authorize(Users="Alice,Bob")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
}
// Restrict by role:
[Authorize(Roles="Administrators")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
}`

The thing is I can have thousands of users, and it has to work right after I create a new user, so Id based

Then use by Role based. Added that as well in the above comment. // Restrict by role: [Authorize(Roles="Administrators")] public class ValuesController : ApiController { }.
